# View doesn't get released completely

Tags: ios, memory-management, uiviewcontroller

**I apologise if this a silly question** but I'm very new to iOS development. So here is the question:

when I add the `SecondView` to the `FirstView`, the memory is allocated but when I remove it, not all of the allocated memory are released.

Here's the code:

FirstView:

```
@interface FirstView : UIViewController
@property (nonatomic, retain) SecondView *secondView;
- (IBAction)loadSecondView;
@end

@implementation ViewController
@synthesize editView;
- (IBAction)loadSecondView{
    secondView = [[SecondView alloc]init];
    [self presentModalViewController:editView animated:YES];
}
- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated{
    [secondView release]; secondView = nil; //this is called after SecondView is removed
}
```

SecondView:

```
@interface SecondView : UIViewController
@end

@implementation EditView
-(void)viewDidLoad{
    for (int intCounter = 0; intCounter < 10000; intCounter++){
        UIImageView *image = [[UIImageView alloc]init]; //create 10000 images just to fill up the memory
        [self.view addSubview:image];

        [image release]; image = nil;
    }
}
@end
```

> Here are some numbers I got from Instruments (Live Bytes):

1. FirstView loaded: **671 KB**
2. SecondView loaded: **3.28 MB**
3. SecondView removed: **809 KB**

**Note: Instruments shows no leak**

**Shouldn't the Live bytes become the initial value (671 KB)? instead of 809 KB, what is left over?**

Comment: why arent you using arc? u shouldnt have to worry about releasing stuff if you do. (only set the pointers to nil and the os will take care of the rest)

Comment: I just migrated the project to arc, still having the same problem.

Comment: what's the problem? no leak means it is good. some memory may used for cache, singleton etc. as long as you program does not have leak and does not crash due to not enough memory, there is no point to figure out what is happening in this low level

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not leak. Apple caches some of the details. First time when you load viewcontroller, it will increase the memory usage. Once you dealloc it, some of the things will remain cached.

So, first readings will not give you exact picture.

Carry the same exercise for 2-3 times. So, you should able to have same memory utilization at the start of 3rd iteration and at the end of 3rd iteration.

If it increases at each cycle, then there might be a case of memory leak.

Comment: Is this applied for objects as well, like, buttons, labels,...?

Comment: No.. If they are allocated with autorelease, then you will not have immediate effect. It will be added into your free memory when autorelease pool is destroyed.